# Choosing how I apply an image to the desktop background(Center, Stretch, Fit, etc) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, html, windows, python-2.7

This is my code to take the Astronomy picture of the day and automatically make it my background every 24 hours. In windows, when you make a background picture you can choose a variety of ways that it is applied. An example would be tiled, or forced to take up the whole screen. I need that ability and cant find anything online.

```
import ctypes
import urllib
import time
import os, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
while True:
try:    
    url = "http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html"
    page = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url))
    for image in page.findAll("img"):
            print "Image: %(src)s" % image
    parsed = "http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/"+"%(src)s" % image
    x = urllib.urlretrieve(parsed)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20, 0,x[0], 0)
    os.remove(x[0])
    time.sleep(86400)
except:
    continue
```

Comment: some info http://code.activestate.com/recipes/435877-change-the-wallpaper-under-windows/

Comment: [This MSDN page](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppSetDesktopWallpaper-eb969505) shows a C++ program that does it, using the same Windows API call. Does that help any?

Comment: Thank you very much! Should have figured it had to do with registry values. Got some code to change them before I load the image and its working great! Thanks!